# IMAP Sort in c#

Tags: c#, imap

How can I send this command:

```
var command = "SEARCH CHARSET UNICODE BODY {5}";
var command2= "icône";
```

to an imap server with c#

I am actually trying to use something like this:

```
 this._sslStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stamp + ((stamp.Length > 0) ? " " : "") + command + "\r\n\r\n"), 0, stamp.Length + ((stamp.Length > 0) ? 1 : 0) + command.Length + 2);
```

I'm blocked, without accent it is ok, with accent, I get no answer

Comment: Also, why do you send two newline pairs? And do you sent a tag for the continuation? That's wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

When encoded as UTF-8, `"icône"` takes 6 bytes, not 5 as you indicate in the command (`{5}`).

Comment: How do you will encode it (code) I dont get the point. Any idea?

Comment: In IMAP you don't just send UTF-8; you normally use something like base64.